# FileNotFoundException at HttpURLConnection.getInputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error for the following code, The error cause of the openStream() I believe, I just want to get the content of the following URL page , the code works great if I change the URL of the instagram page to something else , but if I keep it to the following URL which is Page Not Found for the Instagram page it will cause this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://instagram.com/p/2cZgLGSdIe/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at getURLfinal.getURL.main(getURL.java:17)
```

The Code:

```
public class getURL {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            String url = "";
            String out = new Scanner(new URL("https://instagram.com/p/2cZgLGSdIe/").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            System.out.println(out);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well... `curl -I https://instagram.com/p/2cZgLGSdIe/` returns `HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND` for starters...

Comment: but the page already exist and I would like my code to handle this kind of issue :/

Comment: put a valid url..placing url in browser shows same error

Comment: *"but the page already exist"* - apparently, it *doesn't* exist

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by using `HttpURLConnection` and `getResponseCode()` which it checks if the page is valid return `200` or the page not found `404` , unauthorized `401`

```
            URL url = new URL("https://instagram.com/p/2cZgLGSdIe/");
              HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
              if(con.getResponseCode() == 200){
                  System.out.println("Page is ok!");
              }
              else{
              System.out.println("Page not found 404 /unauthorized 401 ");
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://instagram.com/p/2cZgLGSdIe/ actually returns **404 NOT FOUND**

```
$ curl -I https://instagram.com/p/2cZgLGSdIe/
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
```

So I guess `FileNotFoundException` is the expected behavior...

Comment: Handling that error is broad and can be done in many ways... Do a proper `HttpURLConnection` implementation that intercepts network errors, try/catch blacks, `Picasso`-like libraries etc...

Comment: I have solved the problem with the HttpURLconnection using the getResponseCode() , and check if the respone will be 200 or not otherwise it will be either page not found or unauthorized .. is it good to do it by this way ? since if any page is ok it will give a respone 200 always right ?

Comment: @boudi instead of commenting here, would you please answer your question yourself? Thank you.

Comment: @boudi yes, using `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` is a good practice